# How can I reference jquery library using cgi methods in ruby?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, cgi

I'm completing an assignment for school in which we need to receive information from an html form with a ruby cgi script, and use the fadeIn() jQuery method to display it.

my script looks like:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w

require 'cgi'

cgi = CGI.new('html4')

cgi.out{
  cgi.html{
    cgi.head{cgi.title{"This is a test"}+  cgi.style{"p{color = red;}"}} +
    cgi.body{cgi.p{"Try this " + cgi['ffname'] + ", did that work?"}}
  }
}
```

this was actually some of my test code, to make sure the server was working the way I thought it was.

when I try and use something like:

```
puts "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"
```

the server refuses to run it, so I guess that's not allowed.

I'm still a beginner with the ruby cgi class.

How can I reference the jquery library with these cgi methods?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server-side code and client-side code.  You probably want AJAX.

Comment: I think I do understand the difference.

Here, I'm generating client-side html, with server side ruby.

I'm asking how to generate a jQuery reference.

Comment: That's because you need to learn how to escape quotes in a string.  Read your error messages.

Comment: I wasn't getting error messages from the server, and the ruby code worked fine on my machine. do you think my "puts" expression would work with single quotes?

Comment: yeah, I screwed up with the escape quotes. Thanks for pointing it out, Mr. Grump.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how you are sending html to client side, you will send some javascript code to client side. This javascript code would contain a call to jQuery function.

Comment: that's the problem, I can call the method cgi.script{} and put javascript between the {}, but the reference to the jQuery library is a tag attribute, not script content.

Comment: I have not used Ruby cgi, so I can only talk in general terms. You can try to run a small, hello world javascript snippet that is served by your server side program. If that works then you can try to get jquery to work.

Comment: unfortunately the step from creating a javascript snippet to referencing the jQuery library is a large one, and turned out to be impossible with cgi. because the reference is an option for the tag, and there is no option functionality in the cgi class.

The solution was to echo html code like normal, being careful to use escape characters to quote the link.